# Is there a way to automatically block level-zero Steam profiles?

Tags: steam

Lately, I've been doing a lot of trading on sites like TF2Outpost and backpack.tf, and, within about a minute of bumping my trade, I receive at least 3 friend requests from level-zero private Steam profiles (which is usually indicative of a scammer/phisher). Sometimes, seemingly at random, I'm bombarded with these requests from level-zero bots.

Is there any feature on Steam that **automatically** declines these friend requests by these scammers (or, better yet, blocks them), as I'm sick and tired of blocking bot after bot?

I've checked the settings in Steam, and gone through all the different tabs to try and find such a feature, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I don't think there are any ways to do that. Your best bet would be to just "deal with them." Add them, then block, report, and remove.

Comment: @ShadowZ. The thing is, I can't report them, as they haven't done anything wrong (as far as I know). It's not illegal to have a private and/or level-zero profile.

Comment: There's a least 3 existing discussion to give steam users some options for this on the steam forums : [one](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/622955136053367816/), [two](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/616187839194799824/) and [three](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/38596748478781676/). There might be more but those were the easiest to find.

Comment: Typically if it's trade scammers you'll get a private message as soon as you add them.

Answer (score 3):

Google chrome extension called "steam inventory helper" which can auto decline friend invites under certain levels, you can decide in the settings, I always have it set to auto decline levels 1 and under

Answer (score 1):

Not currently to my knowledge, instead of blocking them, just click ignore, this will prevent unread chat messages from building up, once you ignore a BOT that specific one should not bother you again. it is hassle to deal with them, but non the less, something may be done about this, due to the high demand for something like this.

Comment: Please stop adding signatures to your posts here.  They are irrelevant to the information provided.

Comment: I fail to see the harm caused by using a signature.

Comment: It's something that the SE network in general doesn't allow.  We're looking for encyclopedia-esque content.  Signatures are fluff that don't add anything to the answer, so they are routinely edited out.

Comment: In that case, it should be made more apparent, i suppose this generally answers my other replies to your edits.

Comment: @ESDougie Welcome to the site. Taking the [tour] and browsing the [help] might fill you in on details like this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is a little late but.

I have a work around.
Its not a way to auto-ignore bots but at least make it easier to block the users in a browser (blocking private accounts, unsetup accounts, users under a specific level)
Hope it helps

https://github.com/AndrewParkes/BlockAllSteamInvites

Let me know if you like it

Comment: Hi Andrew, the link is not working anyway it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide a link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Link-only answers (meaning answers where the only useful content comes from a link) are discouraged because the links may die. Since the script is small, you might consider posting the script directly into your post. I have otherwise fixed your broken link.

Comment: It seems to be working for me but here it is again.[BlockAllSteamInvites](https://github.com/AndrewParkes/BlockAllSteamInvites). If it still doesnt work please qoogle BlockAllSteamInvites and it should be the first link